# Matlab, How to copy all the files in a zip file without unzipping?

Tags: matlab, zip

My manager let me do this, because the zip file is so huge and unzipping it takes so long time.
Within a Zip file, I have successfully get all the names of the files but still do not know how to copy all the  files to another folder.Here are the codes for get all the names:

```
zipJavaFile  = java.io.File('filename.zip');

zipFile = org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile('filename.zip')

entries = zipFile.getEntries

filelist={};

while entries.hasMoreElements

    filelist = cat(1,filelist,char(entries.nextElement));

end
```

Thanks for your time and help! You can do me a favor base on my codes, you can also just tell me a better way.

Comment: "how to copy **all the files** to another folder". What exactly do you want to do. If you copy _all_ the file somewhere in an unzipped format, it is the same as unzipping. Or do you want to copy compressed individual files to another zip compressed archive ?

Comment: It's not copy the compressed individual files to another zip compressed archive. A zip file contain lots of files, my manager does not let me extract the zip file, he just let me copy all the files to another folder. I know it is easy to unzip and copy. But I do not know how to get all this files without unzipping the zip file.